# iOS: UIImageView in UITableViewCell can be changed? why I was failed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

This question already has an answer here:

(1) [How to fix UITableView separator on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773239/how-to-fix-uitableview-separator-on-ios-7)

I met the same question as [iOS: UIImageView changes with change in UITableView.rowHeight, how to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25587836/1054800) described, of course, in SO, there were many Q/As like this, and I tried many answers, but I did not get the right result:

(1) when in `...cellForRowAtIndexPath...`:

```
 NSString *CellIdentifier = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *CellLabel = [menuLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = CellLabel;
tableView.rowHeight = 43;

 UIImage* im = [UIImage imageNamed: @"news"];
cell.imageView.image = im;
```

I got the following:
[image]

(2) I tried the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25587986/1054800):
based on (1)'s code, I added:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(32,32), YES, 0);
[im drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
UIImage* im2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
cell.imageView.image = im2;
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

I got another strange picture:
[image]

Append:

I hope I got the following result:

[image]

***here is a continual line under the icon***

Comment: Note: for change height of row you have to use method -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath of the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: the height of row is the key question, I can change it to bigger in `storyboard`, such as 50 or bigger, of course, `tableView.rowHeight = 43;` can work for me, also, whichever way I used to change the height, I got the same result

Comment: Is it your really code or you use subclass of UITableViewCell?

Comment: @stosha, You mean, maybe, my icon is too large?

Comment: try something like this:     tableView.rowHeight = 32.0f;
    UIImage* im = [UIImage imageNamed: @"news"];
    cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
    cell.imageView.image = im;
 instead of (2)

Comment: @stosha, I got the result same as my above first picture

Answer (score 0):

Change the boolean setting of `BeginImageContextWithOptions` from `YES` to `NO` and I believe your weird black background will just go away:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(32,32), NO/*Modified*/, 0);
[im drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
UIImage* im2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

From apple documentation about [UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions), `NO` indicates that it will preserve alpha channel when drawing.

> [void UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ( CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale );](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
>
> **opaque**
>   A Boolean flag indicating whether the bitmap is opaque. If you know the bitmap is fully opaque, specify YES to ignore the alpha channel and optimize the bitmap’s storage. Specifying NO means that the bitmap must include an alpha channel to handle any partially transparent pixels.

Comment: the only difference is that I got the first result without black round pad when changing YES to NO, but thank you!

Comment: @abelard20008, isn't that what you are asking for? If you want to change the size of the image you can change the `32` value to whatever size you want in the `CGSizeMake(32,32)`.

Comment: @Yunchen, I append a picture I hoped in my question , please see it again, thank you

Comment: @abelard20008 Do you want to say that you want to make the image even bigger and with less margin? That seems to be the only difference I can tell from the screenshot you just posted.

Comment: Sorry man, don't really get what you are asking about. You said that you met the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587836/ios-uiimageview-changes-with-change-in-uitableview-rowheight-how-to-avoid. However, matt's solution seems very solid in that answer, changing the contentMode to `UIViewContentModeCenter` will fix the size of the image. So, let me confirm, do you want to change the size of the image with the table view height instead?

Comment: @abelard20008, UITableView×Comments, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Thank you at first. Only I want to extend the line to left side under the image like the third picture in my question. Maybe I did not completely understand the need that author described. Also in many iOS app,  you can see the effect like 3rd picture, such as `zhihu`

Comment: @Yunchen, I am sorry, this was a error because of timeout 5 mins

Comment: @abelard20008, this should be what you are for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773239/how-to-fix-uitableview-separator-on-ios-7

Comment: I only want to say, thank you very very much for your warmheated and time.

Comment: @abelard20008, man, it would be so much easier if you can put your third screenshot upfront and describe the issue without the those unrelated code and unnecessary links. Nice to know that you have what you want.